# If somebody feels they are being attacked by me, how should I respond?

Tags: discussion, etiquette

You think you are helping out the site and correcting a wrong answer.

Maybe you are finding a poster who consistently posts information that you know to be wrong.  The thing to do is to correct them, and provide proof that their assumptions and answers are incorrect.

You are making the Internet better by correcting them and writing out answers with citations that prove your point.  But it isn't working, and that poster isn't changing and now they are arguing with you in the comments, or rolling back your edits.

What to do if that person doesn't *WANT* your help or feedback?

See Also the [Civility Requirement](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/658/civility-is-required-at-all-times-rudeness-will-not-be-tolerated-be-nice) of our site.

Comment: +1 Very nice topic to post. I have seen this happen on few occassions, was not party to it.

Comment: What if a citation is provided, and the "helper" quotes nothing, not even anything from a hack blog, has a much higher rep, and is able to deface your question with personal injections all because a defender's submission is emotionally displeasing?  Just curious.  As a victim, I'd probably use a grease-monkey script so that I never have to endure a high rep hypothetical attacker's emotional outburst again.  Totally hypothetically speaking.

Comment: @Sulla - flag it and move on.  What you do with your browser is your business.

Answer (score 7):

### Be Nice!

Being right doesn't give you a free license to be a jerk or rude.  If you find that you cannot convince another poster that their answer is wrong, write up a counter answer, vote theirs down and move on.

### Be The First to Quit Fighting

If you made an edit to a post, and that poster rolls back your change, then I guess they feel you didn't improve their answer.  Vote it down and move on.

### Be Right

If you are going to be right, then write up a great answer.  Research your topic, provide multiple citations to your points.  Point out the errors is other answers by addressing the idea, not the person who wrote it.

When you answer a question, that bumps it up the home page, which makes it visible and get the question and answers more traffic.  Your answer, if better or correct will earn more votes and that will hide the wrong answer.

Operate on facts, not emotions.

[What Happened To Civility On The Internet?](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/07/whatever-happened-to-civility-on-the-internet.html)

Answer (score 5):

There are also a number of things to consider.

Cultural/Language differences. Some cultures are more blunt about certain things, as in 'hey you got fat over the summer.' Those used to this being ok may not have the same filter on that others do.

History on the site - We, the regular posters, should be extra careful with new guests. The last thing we'd want is to make it seem as if new posters aren't welcome. Yet, at the same time, we need to enforce the 'on topic' rules but do it politely.

Words don't always show the intended feelings. I learned this lesson when I offered an answer where the poster with the name DumbCoder also posted. I gave a hypothetical DumbIndex, which, despite the fact that in my example it beat the market, was offputting to the poster. I apologized, changed it to something else, and exhibited more discretion after that.

Last, there are facts. e.g. the Gift Tax is avoided for $14K this year (US), and then there are questions of opinion. We all need to learn to share our opinions in a way that doesn't offend others. And present the facts kindly.